# How to rotate and move a sprite towards the cursor?

Tags: javascript, graphics, html5-canvas, game-physics

Lets say that I have a player sprite, located at (player.x, player.y). On a mousemove event, I am capturing the cursor's position, which is (e.pageX, e.pageY). In the game, the player will be constantly moving, always towards the direction of the cursor. I am trying to find a way to to rotate the player sprite to always face the mouse cursor, and also move 10 pixels closer to the cursor every game tick. So far, this has me stumped. I have seen many examples of this online, and have tried all of them, but none seem to work. Any help that can be provided would be very much appreciated.

Comment: you should share your attempts (code snippet, fiddle, pen .. ) to get more accurate answers.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you must learn the basics of trigonometry. Without this knowledge, you will can't make something like you want.

Center of you image is the center of an circle. Knowing position of center and mouse position, you can calculate the angle. Calculated angle you can use to rotate image.

[image]